# Error ''Undefined function 'select' for input arguments of type 'database'.''

Tags: database, matlab, odbc

I have created a database connection following MATLAB's documentation instructions
https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/select.html.

```
conn = database('mydb','username','password');
selectquery = 'SELECT * FROM strc_name';
```

And this apparently works fine. 
Then it fails when i type:

```
data = select(conn,selectquery);
```

with

> Undefined function 'select' for input arguments of type 'database'.

Comment: From the documentation to `select`: "Introduced in R2017a". You probably have an older version of MATLAB?

Comment: Yes that's true!

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem following those instructions from the MATLAB documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/exec.html